# send a ViewModel which contains a list with a Html.BeginForm (MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, html.beginform

My viewmodel contains a integer list, the problem I have is that when I send my modified form viewmodel, it is always equal to null.

## My ViewModel :

```
public class testViewModel
 {
    public List<int> itemTest { get; set; 
 }
```

## Action in my Controller :

> For example, I'll try to sum ​​the new values ​​entered into the form, but the sum calculated is always equal to 0, nothing changes.

```
      public ActionResult form(int nbre)
    {
        testViewModel montest = new testViewModel()
        {
            itemTest = new List<int>()
        };

        for(int i=0;i<nbre ;i++)
        {
           montest.itemTest.Add(0);
        }
        return View(montest);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult form(testViewModel maListe)
    {
        int somme = 0;
        if (maListe.itemTest != null)
        {
            if (maListe.itemTest.Count() != 0)
            {

                foreach (var item in maListe.itemTest)
                {
                    somme += item;
                }
            }
        }

        //listtest = maListe;
        return RedirectToAction("test2", new { qte = somme });
    }
```

## My view

```
  @model MvcWebRole1.ViewModels.testViewModel
  @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Formulaire";
   }

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  <table>
  @foreach (var item in Model.itemTest)
  {
    <tr >
       <td >
         @Html.Label("Quantitée")
       </td>
       <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => item)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item)
       </td>
    </tr>

  }
 </table>
   <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
  }
```

Thank you kindly help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to index each item in your collection. The issue with your code seems to be the use of **foreach**. You really want to use **for** instead and pass in the index with the **EditorFor** call.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count; i++) {
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items[i])
 }
```

This only works for ordered lists that will never change their order. If you want to reorder items I suggest your read Phil Haack's great post on sending lists to the server.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 3):

list binding

```
<form>
@for(int i=0;i<Model.itemTest.Count ;i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.itemTest[i])
    //or just <input type="text" name="itemTest "/> working to
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int i=0;i<nbre ;i++)
        {
           montest.itemTest.Add(0);
        }
        return View(montest);
```

Looks like you are filling your int array with zeroes instead of i's. This should read `montest.itemTest.Add(i);` .

Comment: I just wanted to build my list with a number of item (the number is passed as a parameter of the action)