# Make a CheckBox list in Asp.net mvc4 - showing items from Database

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox

Hey This is my model that i joint 3 tables in it.

```
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Simester Semester { get; set; }
    public Lesson Lesson { get; set; }
```

And this is my Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult UnitSelection()
        {
            var students = context.Students;
            ViewBag.Students = new SelectList(students, "Id", "FullName");

            var semesters = context.Simesters;
            ViewBag.Semesters = new SelectList(semesters, "Id", "Title");

            var lessons = context.Lessons;
            ViewBag.Lessons = new SelectList(lessons, "Id", "Title");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UnitSelection(UnitSelectionViewModel model)
        {
            StudnetLesson snl = new StudnetLesson();
            snl.LessonId = model.Lesson.Id;
            snl.StudentId = model.Student.Id;
            snl.SimesterId = model.Semester.Id;
            context.StudnetLessons.Add(snl);
            context.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Success");

        }
```

I want to show a checkbox list in my view in foreach loop.
I want to show Lessons in checkbox list(its string)

```
public Lesson Lesson { get; set; }
```

I tested many codes and It does not work any tips?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UnitSelection", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <text>Student Name: </text>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Student.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Students, "Choose a student")
            <br />
            <text>Semester: </text>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Semester.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Semesters, "Choose your semester")
            <br />
            <text>Lesson: </text>
            foreach (var lessons in (SelectList) ViewBag.Lessons)
            {
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the checkboxes property to your UnitSelectionViewModel

```
public List<string> lessonsList {get;set;}
```

then bind it in view

```
 foreach (var lessons in (SelectList) ViewBag.Lessons)
 {
    <input type="checkbox" name="lessonsList" value ="@lessons.Id" />
 }
```

then in action

```
UnitSelectionViewModel.lessonsList // here must be id of selectd lessons
```

answer on comment.
Id in my script just only for example. Use your name of this field.

for checkboxFor example look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023504/send-a-viewmodel-which-contains-a-list-with-a-html-beginform-mvc-4/17024208#17024208)

Comment: It Does not work. when I write @lessons. it does not show Id in intellisence. It shows some values such as value and text.
Would you please give me example using @html.Checkboxfor()